# American style TV shows in Spanish

Tags: recursos

Are there American style TV shows that could be used to practice listening Spanish.  By American style I mean

- Each episode around 30 minutes in length
- Although it helps to watch them in sequence, each episode has its own plot

<sub>I understand list questions are generally [frowned upon](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/are-questions-about-learning-spanish-on-topic/46#46); however, these could be used to both practice listening comprehension as well as provide exposure to various cultural references.</sub>

Names of specific shows (possibly country of origin) would be very helpful as part of the answer.  This is one of those areas where if you don't know what you're looking for Google can be somewhat unfriendly.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a "list" question, which is not very well suited to SE sites. In other words, there is no "correct" answer select. I don't have any immediate suggestions, but is there some way to make the question more specific?

Comment: I'm voting to close because this question isn't really about Spanish itself, and because of the list aspect.

Comment: @Flimzy: You're right, this is a bit of a list question (as I pointed out in small text), and they are generally difficult to answer.  I had trouble finding Spanish language shows in this format and I'm hoping I'm not the only one looking for such things.

Comment: @NathanGreenstein: I respect that, it's something I've been looking for so I figured it was worth a shot to ask.  There's some precedent for list styles question on the original StackOverflow site in the beginning.

Comment: I agree this question sets a bad precedent. It's very much a list question and not an expert question. It's more suited to a forum than a Q & A site. Can anybody leave a comment suggesting a decent Spanish language forum? We should have some in an FAQ somewhere for standard comments closing such questions.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the translated version of an actual American style show? I would consider "Los Simpson" if I were you...

Although no cultural references. This TV format (30 minutes) is not so popular as far as I know in Latin America. TV series are mostly 1 hour long.

Comment: I have not; however I'd be interested in the cultural aspect of it as well as the language part.  I also have kind of a short attention span so a half hour show would be the sweet spot.

Answer (score 2):

**Soap operas**

My Japanese and English (both native speakers) teachers once told me that is an incredible way to improve your listening skills and learn some of the culture of the country. This also works with others languages.

Comment: Could you recommend specific ones by any chance?

Comment: Well it depends on your taste, what kind of soup opera do you want?

Comment: For me specifically, a Spanish version of [Scrubs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrubs_(TV_series)) or Comedy in general.

Comment: If you want some comedy the 'otro rollo' program specially the monologue part was pretty funny.

Comment: You should probably add that last comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to go to your menu setting and set your subtitle to Spanish so that your audio is in English and the printed subtitle is in Spanish. Also try this with one of your favorite movies, the one you have seen so many times you have lost count, you know the one!  Watch it first all in English, Then with subtitles, Then change your settings so your SAP ( Second Audio Program) is changed to Spanish with your subtitle in Spanish so that you are using both your audio & visual motor skills both at the same time. Repeat this with same program repeatedly. That should serve your purpose.

Comment: Although it is a good suggestion in general, I speak enough Spanish to carry on conversations, I just have trouble following them at full speed (which is why I'm looking for ways to practice listening).